# How to precompile picturefill with rails asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, polyfills, picturefill

I'm using the [polyfill picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) to add support for the `img` attributes `srcset` and `sizes` in browsers like IE.
This polyfill doesn't work when precompiling the javascript in the asset pipeline in rails. It DOES work when I exclude it from the pipeline and include it (picturefill) at the end of my `<body>` tag.

My guess is that picturefill gets executed before the page has fully been loaded (with all 'img' tags). Is this correct? And if so, why didn't the authors add something like a document.ready() event? Is there a way I can solve this more elegant than including the whole script at the end of my body? Adding the script like this seems like a huge performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,
http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/picturefill.html

it looks like turbolinks creates a page:load event, and we can use that event to call the picturefill script